# VBA Checking if filtered table is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if this filtered table is empty because otherwise it ends up copying the entire column when the table has no data. However, when I do it this way, I get an error because specialCells is empty. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this.

```
numberRows = Range("Table13[Store '#]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Style-store report").Select
Cells(7, (3 + ((i - 4) * 3))).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Check that the cells count in Visible range is more than 0, excluding header row.

Comment: Okay how do I count visible cells? When I do SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count, it still returns an error because the first part returns an error. Is there another method to count this

Comment: `Range.Cells.Count` :)

Comment: I tried that. However, when I do Range.Cells.Count and there are no cells in the filtered table, it returns 9962, which is the size of the total table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim rng As Range

'ignore any error if there are no visible rows...
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Range("Table13[Store '#]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0 'stop ignoring errors

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Copy
    Sheets("Style-store report").Select
    Cells(7, (3 + ((i - 4) * 3))).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is check the amount of visible rows of the table, **including the header**, this way, if there are no visible rows you avoid the error of the specialcells being 0 and get at least a count of 1.

```
numberRows = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table13").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count-1
if numberRows>0 then 
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Style-store report").Select
    Cells(7, (3 + ((i - 4) * 3))).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```